# update only latest record in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a collection in which I store student records, each student might have multiple records. I can query them using studentId and it works fine, and it returns me all the records.

I need to update the latest student record. There is an addedAt field in the collection for each record. How can I write this query?

I am using PHP and my current code is :

`

```
$criteria = array("studentID"=>"100010", );
$newdata = array('$set'=>array("status"=>"no")); 
$options = array("upsert"=>true);
$ret = $collection->update(
    $criteria,
    $newdata,
    $options
);
```

Any help is appreciated!
`

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but you can add a sort option in `findAndModify`. Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/de/mongocollection.findandmodify.php). There you can sort by this field `addedAt`

Comment: Try `$options = array(
        "upsert"=>true,
        "sort" => array("addedAt" => -1),
        "new" => true,
    ); $ret = $collection->findAndModify(
     $criteria,
     $newdata,
     null,
    $options
);`